# Customizing Auto-Generated Columns in the DataGrid Control

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

After reading the excellent article on how to [Customize Auto-Generated Columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc903950(v=vs.96).aspx), I have come across an issue.

While trying to customize auto-generated columns in a `DataGrid` control, I want to do simple things like make sure that all numeric column values are right-aligned. To this end, I created a `DataTemplate` as follows:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="MyGrid" AutoGeneratingColumn="MyGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn">
  <DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="IntegerTemplate">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
    </DataTemplate>
  </DataGrid.Resources>
</DataGrid>
```

Then, in the `AutoGeneratingColumn` `DataGrid` event handler, I want to assign this generic `DataTemplate` as the `CellTemplate` for all integral (i.e., numeric) columns:

```
public void MyWindow_AdjustColumnTemplateBasedOnType(
              DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
  if (/*This is a column I want to change*/)
  {
    DataGridTemplateColumn column=new DataGridTemplateColumn(); 

    column.Header=e.PropertyName;
    column.CellTemplate=MyGrid.FindResource("IntegerTemplate") as DataTemplate; 
    e.Column=column; 
  }
}
```

The problem is that the value of the `Text` column of the `TextBlock` does not display the desired results. Instead of seeing the right justified value in each cell whose column has this `DataTemplate` as its `CellTemplate`, I see:

[image]

Using the *empty binding syntax* by setting the attribute `Text` to `"{Binding}"` is obviously incorrect. Setting a path based binding does produce the desired result. That is, if I set a (hard-coded data path) binding using something like:

```
  <DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="IntegerTemplate">
      <!-- Binding hard set to ProductId -->
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding ProductId}" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
    </DataTemplate>
  </DataGrid.Resources>
```

Then all is well, but my generic `DataTemplate` is no longer generic. Instead of it being reusable for all integer columns, it can only be used for the `ProductId` column, because the binding is fixed to the value of that specific data item:

[image]

What is the correct binding I should use so that the generic `DataTemplate` actually uses whatever value is in the corresponding `ItemSource` property for the column with which it is associated.

Comment: @ Michael Goldshteyn :I have the same problem,Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 5):

I believe styles will solve your issue here .

```
        private void MyGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
        {  
            if (/*This is a column I want to change*/)
            {
                DataGridColumn column = e.Column;
                column.CellStyle = MyGrid.FindResource("IntegerTemplate") as Style;

            }
        }
```

and in XAML you can write

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridCell" x:Key="IntegerTemplate">
     <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"></Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: +1 This is exactly how I do it. I use a `Style` instead of a `DataTemplate`

Answer (score 1):

When using a TemplateColumn in a DataGrid context you usually have to use a ValueConverter as well.

This ValueConverter converts the data from you ViewModels object (which is in fact the reason why you want to use a TemplateColum instead of an ordinary TextColumn) to an representable string form.

Do you have such a converter or do you provide a ToString() method in your ViewModels object ? If not try it, maybe that helps ...

Answer (score 1):

For people struggling with the "What is the correct binding I should use so that the generic DataTemplate actually uses whatever value is in the corresponding ItemSource property for the column with which it is associated."

See Jay_Wang's answer in this link:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/8b2e94b7-3c44-4642-8acc-851de5285062

The important bit is overriding the System.Windows.FrameworkElement GenerateElement function so that it can programatically set up the binding to use the column name.

Hope this helps.